# Text overlap in new-questions email messages in iOS Mail when accessibility larger-text setting turned on

Tags: bug, email, feed, accessibility, ios

Email messages from StackExchange announcing new questions in a feed are formatted incompatibly with the iOS accessibility setting “Larger Text”. Other senders’ messages’ text is enlarged, and inter-line spacing enlarged accordingly. But SE messages enlarge their text while holding inter-line spacing constant. This is an accessibility (WCAG) violation and causes the text to overlap, so it can no longer be read. See attached example. The cause seems to be this CSS ruleset:

```
.item-excerpt {
  line-height: 18px;
}
```

The value of line-height should not be in px units, but instead in em or rem units, or the line-height declaration should simply be removed.

[image: example of feed email with illegibly overlapping text]