# Email notices are really hard to read - including overlapping text and side-scrolling

Tags: bug, status-review, email, accessibility

Email notices of new questions matching a filter contain overlapping text. The text is also too small to read, and, when the user enlarges it on a mobile device, it fails to reflow, forcing the user to scroll horizontally on every line in order to read the message.

Both of these facts are violations of WCAG 2.1. Why are the messages formatted that way, when plain text would not cause these problems?

[image: Screenshot of email when viewed on iPhone 7]
[image: Screenshot of email when viewed in Thunderbird on OS X]
[image: Screenshot of Washington Post email when viewed in Thunderbird on OS X]

Comment: It would be helpful if you can give some information about the system you're using to access these emails - it looks like you're on a mobile device - does the same thing happen on a desktop?

Comment: @Catija related/re-post/dupe https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368198/text-overlap-in-new-questions-email-messages-in-ios-mail-when-accessibility-larg

Comment: The screen shot is from Mail on iOS 14.7.1 (iPhone 7). The Larger Text (Larger Accessibility Sizes) setting is on. The amount of text overlap depends on how large the text size is set. The overlap does not occur in Thunderbird on OS X when the text size is enlarged in Thunderbird preferences, but the line breaks are still fixed, and that forces the user to scroll horizontally on every line. I am adding screen shots from Thunderbird, showing this issue with Stack Exchange, and showing that a message from Washington Post reflows, avoiding this issue.